# Swift WKWebView crash on didFailProvisionalNavigation

Tags: ios, swift, exception, switch-statement, webkit

We are encountering an intermittent (happens on some devices, some of the time) crash that we are having a hard time nailing down, and are unable to reproduce on-demand.  This is related to Swift 3 and the WKWebView component, specifically its callback protocol crashes when attempting to get the error code via a switch statement.  see below:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {

  if let err = error as? URLError {

    switch(err.code) {  //  Exception occurs on this line
    case .cancelled:
      Hint(hide: true)

    case .cannotFindHost:
      Hint(hide: false, hint:.CannotFindHost)

    case .notConnectedToInternet:
      Hint(hide: false, hint: .NoInternet)

    case .resourceUnavailable:
      Hint(hide: false)

    case .timedOut:
      Hint(hide: false)

    default:
      Hint(hide: false)
      print("error code: " + String(describing: err.code) + "  does not fall under known failures")
    }
  }
}

func Hint(hide: Bool, hint:SomeCustomEnum = SomeCustomEnum.Default) {
     //Dosomething with ui to let user know something bad happened
}
```

the error stack indicates:

0 _BridgedStoredNSError.code.getter

1 _BridgedStoredNSError.code.getter

2 specialized WebKitController.webView(WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation : WKNavigation!, withError : Error) -> ()

3 @obj WebKitController.webView(WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation : WKNavigation!, withError : Error) -> ()

...

Reviewing the code it seems as if it should be effectively free from issues since the variable err should be successfully optionally-unwrapped as a valid URLError object by the time the switch statement is invoked.  The switch statement at that point should be guaranteed a value in err.code since   .code is not optional for URLError.

Attempts to artificially cause an error that might explain the issue have so far not provided much insight.  ie. if I create my own custom error without a code property, then attempt to cast that as a URLError, it gracefully falls out of the optional assignment.

Any help or suggestions to revolve or even further troubleshoot is appreciated, in the mean time will continue to try to reproduce on a consistent basis.

Comment: Well-written question. Are you accessing URLs on servers you own? If so, do server logs give any insight as to the error that may be causing the crashes in your app?

Comment: That was a great suggestion, but a college of mine was able to reproduce before I could get to it.  Reproduction is to simply navigate with an "http" url with app transport security in default (allow arbitrary loads = no) mode.  Although this does allow us to work around the issue, I'll be submitting a bug based on the cast to URLError which doesn't contain the  .code  property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When looking into the Swift Bug (https://bugs.swift.org) submission site I was able to find a description of the problem, ie. Error cast to URLError can result in the property .code being missing:

https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3879?jql=text%20~%20%22URLError%22

This has a link to the following reference which seems to be the solution (still in process)

https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3881

Effectively URLError is missing two .code definitions:

NSURLErrorAppTransportSecurityRequiresSecureConnection
NSURLErrorDataLengthExceedsMaximum

So if your encountering a crash when referencing the .code property of a URLError, you can check for it by casting to NSError and checking against the NSError .code property.

We are mitigating it with a temporary workaround until the bug is resolved (below only addresses the NSURLErrorAppTransportSecurityRequiresSecureConnection (int -1022) type failures):

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {

  let nserr = error as NSError
  if nserr.code == -1022 {
    Hint(hide: false, hint: .NSURLErrorAppTransportSecurityRequiresSecureConnection)

  } else if let err = error as? URLError {

    switch(err.code) {  //  Exception no longer occurs
    case .cancelled:
      Hint(hide: true)

    case .cannotFindHost:
      Hint(hide: false, hint:.CannotFindHost)

    case .notConnectedToInternet:
      Hint(hide: false, hint: .NoInternet)

    case .resourceUnavailable:
      Hint(hide: false)

    case .timedOut:
      Hint(hide: false)

    default:
      Hint(hide: false)
      print("error code: " + String(describing: err.code) + "  does not fall under known failures")
    }
  }
}

func Hint(hide: Bool, hint:SomeCustomEnum = SomeCustomEnum.Default) {
     //Dosomething with ui to let user know something bad happened
}
```

Comment: Should that be `if  nserr.code == -1022 {` instead of `if let nserr.code == -1022 {` ?

Comment: Yep, please excuse the typo.  Resolving now.